# Sqlite fts4 how to match text by middle letters

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search

How to match text by middle letters? FTS4 can match only by start of words.

some

domestic

omen

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE text MATCH *om*
```

I get only "omen"

Comment: What about the `like` operator: `where text like '%om%'`.

Comment: @forpas I know about it. But FTS4 is more faster. DB must to work fast with 50k rows. I afraid that it will be to slow

Comment: I can't tell. I never used FTS4. Anyway test it.